# Ripped edge pattern on div?

Tags: html, css, background, photoshop, styling

The designer I'm working with has given me a monster of an implementation issue...

Page background is grey, and atop of it is a crumpled paper texture (non-repeating with painted design elements) for the first 600 pixels (by 1400 pixels across; currently centered as a non-repeating background). At the bottom is another div with more text on it -- *with a dropshadow, complex line pattern for the background and ripped edges*, hovered slightly above the top div.

- Saving the top part as a JPG and the bottom part as a transparent PNG leads to filesizes of +1mb.
- Saving the top part as a JPG and the bottom part as a JPG doesn't work very well due to the drop shadow. It would technically work to save the bottom part as a slice with elements of the top part underneath the dropshadow, but it would have to line up pixel-perfect always or else look crappy. And at that point, I might as well save the whole site as one big image...
- If the bottom part had a solid colour for the background, I could set each edge to have a different transparent PNG. However, the line pattern on the bottom part means that this wouldn't work.

My question is ultimately:

**How the heck do people do ripped edges these days without making their site one big image?**

Thanks!

**Screengrab:**

[image: screengrab -- note how the bottom bit overlaps the top texture...]

Comment: Can you provide a screengrab of the design?

Comment: @Dave -- Yeah, just a second...

Comment: As a former designer and current UI Developer, I say fire the designer....

Comment: You're saying for Web & Devices and reducing the quality to the bone, right? It's hard to believe an image like that racking up to 1MB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS3 does provide a `border-image` property, which should be able to help you with the ripped border effect (although even then, it would help if it was a repeating image).

See here for the [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images).

However it may not be much use to you, because browser support for this feature isn't great -- IE doesn't support it at all (not even IE9), and while most other browsers do support it, they all currently have gaps in their support and require a vendor prefix in the CSS property.

See [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=border%20image) for a full browser support table for it.

To be honest, I think you should just go back to your designer and ask him to make it easier to work with -- he's probably just created something he thinks looks good, but is unaware of the limitations of the design he's put together; if you explain the issue to him, he may well be able to produce something a bit more usable for you.

Comment: Accepted as being the most complete and closest to what I was asking. I ultimately just made the thing two big images.

Answer (score 3):

There's really not a whole lot you can do here.

Page edges are ideally seamlessly repeated via `repeat-y`, and in your case it looks like the texture is one big image. You're either going to have to settle for sub-par performance or present the designer with your issues.

Check the [archive of this blog for a good example](https://web.archive.org/web/20110516102541/http://webapplicationdevelopmentindia1.blogspot.com/2011/05/php-developers-demand-are-increasing.html).

Answer (score 2):

You either have to fix the background images and use the entire image (or the top image AND the bottom image) and make the background non-scrolling. OR you have to get him to design a pattern that can repeat and then use a smaller PNG.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, your designer has a print background....

Ok, there's ways that will most likely theoretically work.  But theoretical isn't always practical.  I suspect your desire is to have cross-browser capability, as all of us should.  So, start by throwing most new CSS3 tricks out, thanks to legacy IE.  Forget box-shadow, forget crazy png tranparencies without hacks, etc.

What you're left with is doing a gigantic .jpg background.  That will load....eventually.....

In this case, you can see the storm on the horizon, so run for cover.  Go back to the designer, explain why this is about as smart an idea as texture layered over gradients, and help them understand why our buddies at Microsoft have made this virtually impossible.  Just like a fully-flashed out site, it can be done somehow....but it's probably not the best use of time and resources.  The web isn't print, it's dynamic...and when you put something "on a page" it's not going to stay put as it would in Illustrator, nor can you guarantee that your user is going it experience it in 100# glossy with a metallic overlay.  Yes, I was a designer before I was a developer.....

Sound like a cop-out?  Maybe it is.  But I've been in your shoes, building sites for credit cards.  My team was forced to waste thousands of dollars of the bank's money trying to make sites work with designs that probably shouldn't have been done on the web, thanks to print designers doing double-duty, getting designs approved prior to talking to the tech team....after, of course, we presented management with the options.  Ultimately, it got the boss fired for going over budget.

Answer (score 0):

although this is untypical, I would recommend cutting a big square shaped hole in the center of the image so that you're only left with the edges themselves and a transparent center and saving to PNG. Then saving the center part itself as a jpeg and putting the jpeg directly on top of the PNG in the correct position.

This way, the majority of the very large PNG will contain very little data and be a very small file size. The rest of the data would then, obviously, be jpeg and therefore smaller.